# How to set Powershell's Default Browser eg when opening MS auth popup

Tags: powershell, browser

OK so this is a tough one, because googling "set powershell Default Browser" only returns results for setting the system default browser in Powershell. What I want to do is change which browser Powershell uses to open an auth prompt when I attempt to use the Exchange Online Management module. I need to change it because I set "use always" when I chose Edge the first time it popped up, then received a message that Edge is blocked by your administrator. (Weirdly, Edge is not blocked normally, only in this context.) I'm running powershell as local PC admin. (Could this be an Azure/m365 policy blocking edge launch from powershell? Intune managed device. ) I need to change it to Chrome.

Using PS7 as 5 just told me "browser unsupported" (guessing it defaults to IE)

Thanks

Tried numerous google search varying wording, still getting same results about system default browser.
Checked properties of powershell, no browser settings apparent unless I'm blind.

Comment: The OS controls your defaults, not PS. You can use PS to set your OS default browser. You can do this via a proper registry setting. ***So, this can be seen potentially as a duplicate or close enough to this*** [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69395209/set-microsoft-edge-as-default-browser-with-powershelll). Or just use the ```Start-Process``` as or .Net namespace needed to launch a URL in a target browser. I.E., ```[system.Diagnostics.Process]::Start('msedge','https://https://stackoverflow.com')```

Comment: Also, point of note: [Microsoft will be removing IE in Windows](https://www.pcmag.com/news/microsoft-to-remove-internet-explorer-for-good-with-upcoming-windows-update) going forward.